# How to scrape the site that there is robot detection page in front page

Tags: python, wordpress

I want to scrape following site:
https://www.mejorescomparativas.es/
But this site is redirected by robot detection function.
How can I scrape the site?
Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: what did you use to scrape it? `requests` + `beautifulsoup` or [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or `scrapy` or something different? First you could try [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which control real web browser.

Comment: Hello, Mr. furas.
Thanks for your comment.